# UIImageView automatically removing itself from self.view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

```
tutorialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tap to Start.png"]];
tutorialImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[tutorialImage addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blankMethod)]];
tutorialImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // i use this line and the previous line so that the user can't press any buttons behind the image
tutorialImage.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:tutorialImage];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:tutorialImage];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    tutorialImage.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.view addSubview:tutorialImage]; // this line makes the image come back
}];
```

I know you probably won't be able to deduce the problem just from this code, but is there anything in that code that makes the tutorialImage auto remove itself from it's superview?

Anyway, during the UIView animation the image fades in for a bit like normal, then it disappears. If I add that last line of code there (the commented one), the UIView animation will make the image fade in and flash once halfway through. I just added this image and there is no code telling it to remove itself from superview.

Let me know if you have any ideas as to fixing the problem or showing you more code, I'll check frequently.

Also, I've tried restarting the simulator which didn't work, and the tutorial image is declared in the h file `UIImageView *tutorialImage;`. The console doesn't show any errors or anything when the problem occurs or anything.

Edit:

Ok, strange. I altered the declaration in the H file from `UIImageView *tutorialImage;` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *tutorialImage;` then used _tutorialImage fixed the problem. Is this something to do with the strong parameter? I'll mark who ever can explain what was going on as correct.

Comment: Has any one else come across any problem like this before?

Comment: That is odd. For purposes of this code, there should be no practical difference between the ivar and the property, at least as far as prematurely releasing the view goes. Interested to find out the answer as well.

Comment: Are there any other places in your code where you use the `tutorialImage` property or ivar?

Comment: only after the uiview completion.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a weak reference, ARC will dealloc the object once there are no more retains on it (when no object is pointing at the object with a strong pointer). When you changed the @property to strong, you are now telling ARC to keep the object around until the parent (your view controller) is dealloc'ed.